# Controlo de cache para um ficheiro especifico

Tags: apache, arquivo, htaccess, cache

Se pretendemos implementar um controlo de cache para um tipo de ficheiros em particular, através do `htaccess` podemos proceder da seguinte forma:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Mas isto é uma solução para todos os ficheiros de determinado tipo, no exemplo em cima, para ficheiros de JavaScript.

## Pergunta

Como aplicar controlo de cache para um ficheiro especifico, por exemplo: `script.js` ?

Answer (score 2):

Analisando a [documentação do `mod_expires`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_expires.html) parece não ser possível diferenciar arquivos a não ser pelo tipo.

Alternativas que consigo pensar são:

1. Usar uma extensão diferente de `js` para o arquivo específico e associá-la a outro *mime type* que dê o mesmo resultado.
2. Aplicar diferentes configurações de expiração para diferentes diretórios.

Exemplo do item #2 ([fonte](https://serverfault.com/a/564316)):

```xml
<Directory /var/www/js/expire_fast>
  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 60 minutes"
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```